# Why don't I see myself under MyTasks under View?

Tags: mytask

I am using SharePoint 2013. I created a Task List. I assigned one task item to myself. Why isn't that task item showing up when I go to the mytask view?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot, because I can't see any reason why is it not coming under My Tasks view.